# Edited a template file then uploaded it via FTP but changes does not reflect in website

Tags: php, wordpress, sftp

It was a website that I am in charge of from a different developer. I tried to edit a page-homepage.php (template) in a child-theme just to correct a misspelled text but the changes do not reflect in the website. I already cleared the cache of my browser, tried different browser & computer, and ctrl+refresh/ ctrl+shift+refresh but to no avail.

I downloaded the file in the server after uploading it and checked if my changes are there, and there they are.

I'm guessing the host provider has a cache saved or something. I want to contact them but the person in-charge (has the credentials, took a month before giving me ftp/sftp log in credentials) seldom replies to my emails.

Is there any other way for me to diagnose the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Notes:
CMS = Wordpress
Port = 2222

Comment: Wordpress caches, clear the cache

Comment: is there any caching plugin installed in your website ?

Comment: http://wpexplorer-themes.com/total/docs/clear-site-cache/

Comment: wow. That's some fast response right there. @ManthanDave There are no caching plugin installed. Zanderwar, I will try to clear the cache in wordpress. Will update you guys soon. Thank you very much.

Comment: @wordpressDev sure happy to help you and keep helping :)

Comment: @ManthanDave Can i ask a somewhat related question to this topic? The website uses Jupiter-Child Theme, and while searching around the server via ftp client, i found the jupiter folder. But I got confused because there are no jupiter-child theme folder. I reckon the developer renamed it to the website's name but the theme in the wordpress cms still recognizes it as a child theme of Jupiter. And there is this page-homepage.php in the child theme folder that i needed to edit but that file, I cannot find in the parent folder. Is that weird? Am i missing something?

Comment: @wordpressDev have you checked wp-content/theme/jupiter-child theme folder is there , have you checked that ?

Comment: yeah. No jupiter-child theme folder. Only the website's name. I think he/she renamed it. @ManthanDave

Comment: @wordpresDev no  worries , you can check from your wp-admin ->appearence ->themes -> you can see over here which theme is active what is the name of it (if they renamed)

Comment: @ManthanDave. I did mate. The current theme is Jupiter-Child Theme but there are no folders named like that. Thats why i got confused.

Comment: Hi guys. Tried everything from "Clear Theme Cache" to "Purge all Caches" but still no luck. I also cleared my browser cache before checking. Any other ideas?

Comment: i thought child themes were for styles. (??) don't you have to change the theme itself, not something in the child theme?

Comment: ah, nvmnd. https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Template_Files